# How to change the format of data in a plot label?

Tags: r, date, plot, axis, date-formatting

Good afternoon,

Have a problem with the first (horizontal, x) axis of a plot. In the `data$datum` column there is a series of dates from 2020-03-10 until 2023-03-31. Want to show them as a label of the first (horizontal, x) axis in the `format = "%d.%m.%Y` (10.03.2020 and 31.3.2023). However, when I put the format as an argument to the `axis(1,)` parameter it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```r
pozicedat <- seq(1, length(runif(length(data))),2)

plot(ts_obrat_dek$x, main = "Obrat ČEZ", xlab = NULL, ylab = "obrat [CZK]", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", col = "blue")
axis(1, at = pozicedat, labels = seq.Date(min(data$datum), max(data$datum), length.out = length(pozicedat)))
axis(2, at = c(min(data$obrat), max(data$obrat)), labels = c(min(data$obrat), max(data$obrat)))
```

Already tried to modify the format like that: `axis(1, at = pozicedat, labels = seq.Date(min(data$datum), max(data$datum), length.out = length(pozicedat)), format = "%d.%m.%Y")`, but with no effect.

Would be grateful for any advice.

**EDIT**

Thank [jpsmith][1] for reminding me. However, the object is too big for postin there and I don't know how to attach it, so I send the original object. The ts_obrat_dek object was created by decomposing this object with the `decompose()` function (sorry if I use the `dput()` function incorrectly):

```r
structure(c(20752, 99571, 187949, 92989, 190612, 277529, 171674, 
193976, 269749, 134440, 1028960, 121366, 315718, 334789, 253836, 
244521, 257050, 397989, 550677, 250164, 920370, 251201, 423512, 
477058, 270449, 285683, 602298, 461080, 386368, 336436, 654705, 
935267, 707249, 725969, 461968, 518128, 241572, 366018, 713819, 
277850, 417587, 205856, 224392, 610803, 281371, 613072, 498956, 
499912, 265113, 283138, 252390, 243635, 86812, 223148, 245255, 
170360, 217598, 281106, 235629, 252198, 118353, 168430, 196928, 
315510, 70671, 165449, 81490, 103838, 56807, 165105, 138946, 
90814, 125585, 184920, 546828, 91740, 106820, 237343, 177276, 
170363, 627871, 320867, 287904, 194372, 272199, 111909, 678775, 
109171, 65972, 106320, 99505, 266426, 175393, 239529, 181977, 
188157, 173782, 347051, 305941, 454668, 382152, 226189, 358582, 
191455, 177398, 211582, 192062, 264289, 150799, 278756, 193471, 
305991, 392830, 608207, 752027, 320500, 383044, 441268, 387833, 
323045, 690380, 416357, 453976, 323785, 252965, 194669, 202189, 
390511, 342549, 215892, 195060, 83652, 182539, 246527, 268527, 
157424, 856207, 215141, 293312, 371416, 294631, 365002, 345271, 
567456, 263732, 450539, 298579, 602583, 606080, 227537, 357596, 
151160, 234205, 166380, 235471, 244444, 232566, 108413, 261218, 
245987, 114680, 211185, 221406, 224858, 307419, 195901, 114317, 
150294, 324850, 670378, 437269, 454267, 137648, 441229, 251786, 
197588, 145330, 213723, 249254, 509217, 366845, 313757, 178497, 
163426, 229745, 224177, 509236, 437860, 677874, 613406, 476453, 
255881, 500770, 1074064, 244073, 428923, 226733, 157357, 249218, 
574028, 209792, 182709, 176817, 221374, 220044, 347973, 252055, 
259182, 103154, 180247, 227951, 219599, 899820, 145275, 294363, 
345702, 338923, 441956, 615249, 626492, 461942, 885902, 396359, 
178716, 219786, 252339, 275395, 404581, 197103, 234717, 318526, 
208780, 99888, 123459, 226971, 301559, 149900, 217504, 172677, 
108893, 130281, 236915, 404426, 236731, 268202, 280259, 172266, 
414315, 364436, 208786, 288635, 206950, 440764, 661849, 347545, 
132308, 63922, 110459, 241809, 221528, 181859, 167739, 1044871, 
208296, 245487, 212851, 277179, 271121, 227527, 389417, 472730, 
665681, 537099, 459520, 737840, 709830, 620435, 510074, 783633, 
383194, 475595, 323022, 163902, 116748, 187734, 137638, 457750, 
136688, 279362, 410779, 309104, 297546, 465277, 229032, 264464, 
235989, 227549, 126975, 208777, 198970, 424683, 451735, 155403, 
161879, 159121, 219800, 138865, 398607, 160822, 157761, 250709, 
112036, 135377, 130038, 305318, 227942, 427134, 148182, 27466, 
82243, 156897, 458059, 298798, 472344, 233521, 715377, 396422, 
157524, 302473, 244793, 498095, 680341, 889521, 460228, 287004, 
369380, 241728, 319196, 835451, 306235, 347666, 226632, 149052, 
425216, 316461, 323867, 437552, 265231, 167879, 323292, 325885, 
205690, 303245, 412772, 248303, 301421, 488306, 401536, 376926, 
619044, 308372, 226159, 361519, 360713, 954899, 405305, 421988, 
481588, 357492, 563521, 209433, 189806, 287343, 730385, 1319841, 
1483050, 752904, 591284, 645587, 428792, 190339, 129043, 170308, 
152073, 182349, 125628, 310932, 725480, 480599, 222051, 169222, 
106120, 113629, 81093, 79303, 94104, 63808, 100977, 161907, 271749, 
374387, 184003, 112789, 304891, 280364, 165849, 135669, 141139, 
277046, 419445, 432951, 190960, 172522, 65960, 184582, 253108, 
259914, 147479, 100011, 207667, 279984, 139315, 227826, 134180, 
105880, 137738, 176177, 68740, 53035, 75110, 194625, 360182, 
166694, 123293, 90012, 143339, 94671, 110699, 247849, 196041, 
143213, 436889, 1078018, 284918, 179277, 323513, 170070, 74499, 
76852, 99950, 363817, 231870, 344132, 175016, 109709, 217275, 
130006, 150659, 161574, 149620, 256325, 185837, 179426, 238151, 
121164, 139070, 583817, 278971, 307990, 174701, 404394, 169126, 
321460, 200217, 144776, 84860, 196605, 199334, 192995, 237076, 
127167, 129299, 194072, 181319, 100697, 247766, 236688, 180369, 
107724, 221290, 244358, 324843, 206313, 188502, 176619, 260382, 
389350, 305512, 655667, 280469, 163983, 169916, 252905, 125554, 
91137, 304452, 209685, 191748, 162712, 335255, 558206, 171585, 
320594, 687793, 357282, 129045, 212793, 135221, 220164, 385825, 
206292, 131424, 106310, 272088, 205037, 338141, 139808, 169997, 
384868, 179149, 210521, 284040, 483132, 308568, 180705, 242068, 
278509, 81063, 85589, 108069, 160275, 111845, 144799, 171153, 
125731, 268887, 238268, 250422, 382617, 221600, 186574, 165364, 
365781, 168427, 118513, 297828, 248774, 117357, 138895, 212752, 
249072, 214989, 311024, 401221, 218646, 279010, 212330, 141094, 
198544, 225437, 233251, 190984, 102206, 299886, 780658, 410903, 
288884, 261001, 103694, 171783, 489708, 125471, 369676, 265388, 
236998, 312422, 319598, 146161, 872151, 168075, 124869, 148134, 
126895, 196009, 93970, 168952, 196025, 179356, 171265, 181831, 
142265, 342709, 265203, 167761, 215507, 187622, 109104, 93240, 
216232, 191605, 225336, 62187, 246702, 658101, 185708, 114219, 
95948, 213275, 120618, 101154, 62440, 296791, 48278, 76157, 205828, 
89144, 116089, 118332, 74799, 278725, 83916, 90620, 147143, 111773, 
247904, 149799, 401517, 259343, 112292, 179750, 60563, 71145, 
113991, 117181, 131246, 48325, 186876, 176780, 147574, 101277, 
311625, 132565, 87799, 138776, 138382, 161208, 151413, 117702, 
193125, 155315, 18772, 96262, 158612, 112883, 188471, 128252, 
219176, 142020, 105173, 179173, 221776, 442115, 201236, 149116, 
231238, 115693, 201025, 100576, 132225, 156414, 119359, 115757, 
295915, 258228, 191284, 136477, 147535, 115571, 81168, 286306, 
88116, 365706, 427697, 436230, 143830, 256995, 143570, 73022, 
153751, 83883, 811529, 236156, 124619, 122093, 133741, 133721, 
395768, 115157, 325685, 263414, 180653, 301784, 314207, 275264, 
183949, 857244, 316787, 287638, 149827, 117789, 171652, 183692, 
124475, 167510, 129533, 126271, 260331, 202282, 306278, 276451, 
361408, 260508, 201396, 394891, 224764, 211358, 288464, 171958, 
377038, 448085, 295267, 240696, 359944, 453035, 499369, 686667, 
13517, 289738, 186140, 365956, 296878, 308402, 252256, 340797, 
427780, 497266, 555725, 778806, 774041, 710129, 569179, 1483372, 
938237, 1082674, 1326790, 1642382, 1336187, 1450006, 575743, 
491550), tsp = c(1, 3.10684931506849, 365), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Could yo make this question reproductive with sample data, or using `dput(ts_obrat_dek)`?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that dates in R are generally tagged as integers which represent the number of days since 1/1/1970.  The "date" in your `ts` object looks like it is continuous because of the `tsp = c(1, 3.10684931506849, 365)`.

Let's try a reproducible example.

```
time.data <- data.frame(dates = seq(as.Date('2020-03-10'), as.Date('2023-03-31'), 
               length=365), Y = rnorm(365))
time.data$dates <- as.Date(time.data$dates, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

```
> time.data[1:5,]
dates           Y
1 2020-03-10  0.24180769
2 2020-03-13  0.25842223
3 2020-03-16 -0.18405168
4 2020-03-19 -0.54766840
5 2020-03-22 -0.01880804`
```

See if this works for you:

```
plot(Y ~ dates, time.data, xaxt = "n", type = "l")
axis(1, time.data$dates, labels=format(time.data$dates, "%d.%m.%Y"), cex.axis = .7)
```

[image: Time series with correct x axis]

You will have to specify your `at =`  argument, but this should get you started.

You may want to take a look at `ggplot` for more flexibility in your plots.  The learning curve is steep but it gives you more flexibility in your plots, especially time series plots.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = time.data, aes(x = dates, y = Y)) + 
  geom_line(color="blue") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months", labels = date_format("%d.%m.%Y")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]